# NPM Module - How to leverage the package.json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm writing a NPM module for a cli-based tool. After someone installs the package, I need to read their `package.json` file. I know how to read the file in syntax. My question is, how can I consistenly retrieve the `package.json` file and should I use relative or absolute paths.

So, after installing, my code would reside somewhere inside the `node_modules` folder:

```
package.json // I need to require this file
node_modules/
  ↳ my-package/
    ↳ dist/
      ↳ my-package.js // the actual file running the code
```

Any suggestions/best practices? Or is it just a matter of using the right filepath?

Comment: Generally the way I've seen it done is to look in the current working directory (i.e. where the CLI command is being run from) - you can use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) to get that directory's path. I've also seen quite a few tools continue to search up the folder structure if there's no package.json in the CWD, as this means you can run the command from a subfolder of the project and it'll still work.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback! The answer below is a little more informative, but it's useful to know your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the package.json file is very easy, as you can simply require it:

```
var package = require('./path/to/package.json');
```

Finding the right path is what's not so simple.

This is quite a common task and there is no simple way to achieve that with core modules but there are few modules on npm that can help you with that.

find-package-json:

> Easily find package.json files that you're searching for. It spiders parent directories for package.json files and correctly reads the results. It follows an ES6 iterator design so it should be easy to implement.

parent-package-json:

> Using parent-package-json, you can find the parent package.json, so the package.json of the module that uses your module.

find-and-read-package-json:

> Find and read data from a package.json file.

See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-package-json
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/parent-package-json
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-and-read-package-json